# how to take a number and returns an array of strings javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, numbers, push

exercise:
Create a function that takes a number and returns an array of strings containing the number cut off at each digit.
examples:
420 should return ["4", "42", "420"];
2017 should return ["2", "20", "201", "2017"]

This is my code, how can I make it less more declarative? can`t find solution without push.
and yes it take me a lot of hours to try to resolve it in declarative way.thanks.

```
 function createArrayOfTiers(num) {
        arrT= num.toString().split("")
      let z= []
      const result = arrT.reduce((acc, curr)=>{
      acc= acc+curr
      z.push(acc)
      return acc

      },"")
          return z;
      }
```

PS: The input is guaranteed to be an integer in the range [0, 1000000]

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by _declarative_ ?

Comment: if you work with JavaScript you must know declarative and imperative programming. if not, check functional programming for more knowledge.

Comment: I work with Javascript, alot. However, I've never came across those terms. I will do some research on the subject since it seams like an interesting topic. Thank you for the informations.

Answer (score 1):

You could get a string and return an array from it by using a closure which kees the previous characters.

[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) works with an [iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#Built-in_iterables), the string and the array has only a single character as value.

The following mapping takes a closure of an empty string. This closure returns a function for the mapping. `v` is an element of the array, like the standard [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) callback.

```
Array.from(
    number.toString(),          // take iterables
    (s => v => s += v)('')      // map value of array with the previous elements
)
```

```js
const getParts = number => Array.from(number.toString(), (s => v => s += v)(''));

console.log(getParts(2017));
```

Comment: can you please explain more? are you using currying? I can not understand where v is coming from. thank you very much @ninaScholz